# If a set is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that each component is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is the definition of bounded:

> A metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be bounded, and $d$ is said to be a bounded metric, if there exists a positive real number $M$ such that $d(x,y)<M$, for all $x,y\in X$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $d$ the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $X$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $X$ is bounded in $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)$ if and only if there exists a positive real number $M$ such that for all $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in X$, $-M<x_i<M$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

I am trying to show that the above definition of boundedness is equivalent to showing there is an open ball from the origin large enough that the set is contained in the open ball, but I'm getting stuck doing so. Can someone provide some pointers?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: I tried defining a function F which is the supremum of the distance from the origin to any point on the set X. But then I realized I can't do that because I need to show that the distance from the origin to any point on the set is bounded, but that is actually what I'm trying to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Assume that $|x_i|<M$ for all $i$. Then:

1. Consider the value $x_i^2$. Can you find an upper limit for it?
2. Use the fact that if $a_1 < b_1$ and $a_2< b_2$, then $a_1 + a_2 < b_1 + b_2$.

Comment: this direction is easier to show. Using the Euclidean metric formula, the distance from any point to the origin should be less than sqrt(n)M, then we can use the triangle inequality  on any two points on the set is less than 2(sqrt(n)M

Comment: @William Well, the other is even simpler. If $\|x\|\leq M$, then it should be extremely simple to show that $\forall i: |x_i| \leq M$.

Comment: no, the other direction says, if the set is bounded which is defined to be the distance between any two points in the set, and then show each point is less than distance M from the origin which I can then show each component is less than M

Comment: @William If a set $A$ is bounded, then clearly (i.e., after a proof of exactly one line), there exists some $M$ such that for all $x\in A$, you have $\|x\|\leq M$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as follows; the distance between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ is $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2}.$$

Now suppose that $X$ is bounded, so there is some $M$ such that for every $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ in $X$ we have $d(\vec{x},\vec{y})<M$. We suppose now that there is some component $i$ which is not bounded. That is, we have some $\vec{x}$ such that $|x_i|$ is not bounded. Can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: if one of the component is not bounded, then we can make it as large as we want, so it can be large enough such that d(xi,yi) > M which would automatically mean d(x,y) > M .

Comment: the part that is giving me some trouble is that fact that the set itself could be located very far away from the origin, even if the set itself is not that large